How to create a species distribution map for the African continent with ggplot?
I'm trying to build a species distribution map for Africa with ggplot. I've managed to make the same type of map for a few American states, but when it comes to the whole African continent, R returns an error message. It seems to be due to the way I've defined the African continent, but I can't work out what the problem is. Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.
Here is my script:
Bulbo<-subset(bulbostylis_occ,bulbostylis_occ$genus=='Bulbostylis')
Bulbo$genus<-as.factor(Bulbo$genus)
colnames(Bulbo)[1]<-'Bulbostylis'

world <- map_data("world")
africa <- subset(world, region %in% c("Algeria","Angola","Benin","Botswana","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cabo Verde","Cameroon","Central African Republic","Chad","Comoros",
"Democratic Republic of the Congo","Republic of Congo","Ivory Coast","Djibouti","Egypt","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Swaziland","Ethiopia","Gabon","Gambia","Ghana","Guinea","Guinea-Bissau","Kenya","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Madagascar","Malawi","Mali","Mauritania","Mauritius","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Niger","Nigeria","Rwanda","Sao Tome and Principe","Senegal","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Somalia","South Africa","South Sudan","Sudan","Tanzania","Togo","Tunisia","Uganda","Zambia","Zimbabwe"))

Bulbo_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = africa, map = africa,
           aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region),
           color = 'black', fill = "azure", size = 0.2) + 
  coord_map() +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = 'Elevation (m)', low = 'white', high = 'black') +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-20, 52), ylim = c(-35, 35)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(decimalLongitude), 
                           y = as.numeric(decimalLatitude),
                           colour = Bulbostylis,
                           fill = Bulbostylis,
                           shape = Bulbostylis),
             data = Bulbo, cex = 0.25) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = 'Bulbostylis', values = c(22, 21, 24, 23)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('grey26', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('grey76', '#1E88E5', '#FF880A', '#8C0808')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
pdf(file = "attempt.pdf",   # The directory you want to save the file in
    width = 8,
    height = 8) 

And here is the error message:
Warning message:
In geom_map(data = africa, map = africa, aes(x = long, y = lat,  :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x and y


Welcome to SO, Siromenthe! You don't actually have an error here, just a warning. The map renders perfectly fine. You are using the geom_map() function, as opposed to geom_polygon() or even geom_sf(), and geom_map() as it happens is a bit of an older function. As the documentation states, geom_map() does not understand x and y inside the aesthetics aes(). Really the only required aesthetic is map_id. I ran your code with aes(map_id = region) and did not receive the warning.

Thank you! It is good to know. Indeed I managed to get the map eventually.
